# how to update data using transaction when triggering onCreate using cloud function in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I watch this video to update data in realtime database using transaction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPKA88_FmkA , but it seems transcation is not available on firestore cloud function?

so I have firestore data like this, and I want to update rankPoint when new attendee is added in the subcollection.
[image]

here is the code I use to trigger the function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()


exports.increasePointWhenAddingNewAttendee = functions.firestore
    .document('Events/{eventId}/Attendee/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const eventID = context.params.eventId
        const eventRef = snap.ref.firestore.collection('Events').doc(eventID)

        // increase rankPoint
        return eventRef.transaction(rankPoint => {
            return rankPoint + 1
        })



    });
```

but it doesn't work properly, from the log it is said:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video you're watching is about Realtime Database triggers, which are very different then Firestore triggers.  They don't have the same API.

If you want to perform a transaction with Firestore, you need to call runTransaction on a Firestore object, not a DocumentReference object.  Please refer to the documentation for [Firestore transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).  Again, the way it works with Firestore is different than Realtime Database.